# How to prevent model from recognizing false Classes

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification, keras, image-classification

Let's say that I have a model that can recognize Cats and Dogs. However, when I use a picture of a Cup or Human it generates a random prediction at 0.70 confidence. Should I use sigmoid instead of softmax?

Or is there any fix for preventing massive confidence on new class object?

Comment: For binary classification sigmoid is softmax. So it shouldn’t matter much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually played around with this problem, but here are a few resources:

- [AI.se question - Why not teach to a NN not only what is true, but
  also what is not true?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/why-not-teach-to-a-nn-not-only-what-is-true-but-also-what-is-not-true/7139)
- [How to Make a Neural Network say "Don't Know"?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020025517311234) (maybe try
  requesting fulltext through [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321316148_How_to_Make_a_Neural_Network_say_Don't_Know) )
- [blog post - Making Your Neural Network Say “I Don’t Know” — Bayesian
  NNs using Pyro and PyTorch](https://towardsdatascience.com/making-your-neural-network-say-i-dont-know-bayesian-nns-using-pyro-and-pytorch-b1c24e6ab8cd)

Edit: I just found the following questions here on DS.se:

- [Multi Class + Negative Class Image Classification Strategies](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/32289/55122)
- [Fine-tuning a CNN for recognizing two classes, but also being able to tell if none of them is present in an image](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/27807/55122)